# Get remote git-svn branch for current local branch

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm looking for a snippet that will give me the "pseudo-remote" upstream branch used by git-svn for the currently checked out branch.

Let's say my local repository was cloned from svn with `git svn clone -s --prefix=my-svn/ ...` and I'm on some local branch `topic/foo` based on svn branch `bar`.

How can I figure out which branch under `refs/remotes/` would be updated by a `git svn fetch --parent`? (Preferrably without hard-coding any layout information configured in the initial clone.)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
git log --grep git-svn-id: --first-parent -1
```

Then query the `[svn-remote]` section in your `.git/config` file (use git config) and see which branch the `svn-url` obtained from the command above corresponds to.